# Where does SXA store the physical files "sitemap.xml" and "robots.txt"?

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA 1.8 with my Sitecore 9.1 instance.

I have a tenant and 2 sites Site A and Site B underneath it. For Site A, I have configured the sitemap settings in **Search Engine Sitemap** section using Sitemap Mode "**Store in File**".

After saving and publishing, I see that my sitemap gets generated. However, I am unable to find the physical location of this.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generated in `TempFolder`.

By default it's just `"/temp"` folder inside your web application.

But this can be overriden with `TempFolder` setting, e.g.:

```
<setting name="TempFolder" value="/some-other-temp-folder"/>
```

Sitemap file name is `sitemap-NAME_OF_THE_SITE.xml`

As far as I know, SXA `robots.txt` content is never stored in a file.

Comment: It looks like in 1.8.1, there may be a bug with this. My sitemaps are all created as `sitemap-website.xml`, and whichever sites sitemap is called first after a publish, that is the one that all sites are getting.

Comment: Interesting. Have you raised Support ticket? Or pinged Adam? ;)

Comment: In the process :)

Comment: @MarekMusielak, yes I found it. 

It gets generated in the `"/temp"` folder. The file name is `"sitemap-shell.xml"`.

But shouldn't the name be site-specific?? 

Also, should I be getting two sitemap files for each site??

Comment: @RuchiYevle I believe there might be a bug in saving to file. See the comment above from Richard

Comment: @MarekMusielak yep, thanks!

Comment: Yeah - I confirmed with the SXA team, its a known bug. I would stick to `Stored in cache`